# NewEnvironment in LaTeX - Trouble Passing Arguments

Tags: environments

I'm trying to make a new environment to format all my tables for this document, but it keeps surprising me. Here's the code:

```
%Format for Title Sections
\newcommand{\mytitle}[1]{{\fontfamily{lmss}\textbf{\textsc{#1}}}}

%Format for Tabulars
\newenvironment{mytabwb}[3][\unskip]
    {\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
    \begin{center}
    \rowcolors{2}{white}{blue!05}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{ #1}    
    \begin{tabular}{ #2}
    { #3\rowcolor{white}
    \hline
    }}
    { 
    \\
    \end{tabular} 
    \end{center}
    }
```

Here's the call in the document:

```
\begin{mytabwb}{1.1}{l|l}{}
\mytitle{Likes} & \mytitle{Dislikes}\\ \hline
\end{mytabwb}\\
```

Here's the output & the desired output:

[image: As-Is & Desired]

What am I doing wrong? I am fairly new to LaTeX. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are defining `mytabwb` to take 3 arguments, the first of which `#1` is optional with a default of `\unskip`. That is causing an error since `\arraystretch` doesn't accept being `\unskip`. Then there are other errors...

Comment: Thank you! How should I go about fixing this?

Comment: Actually, I think I figured it out. How do I format comments like you did when you fixed my post?

Comment: it's hard to suggest how to fix, what is teh intention of the default value `[\unskip]`  it's clearly wrong to use it in `\arraystretch` but where did you intend it to b eused?

Comment: I had thought it would be nice to provide an option to include a formatted title, but I ended up gutting that feature & I got the code to run.

Comment: do you want to delete the question, or you could post an answer, I am not sure anyone else can answer as it is currently